# Counter on scroll in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make make my counter work when scrolling.

I have tried Google, StackOverflow and other different sites and the web is full with examples but I cannot figure it out. Can anyone give a tip please?

I have also tried to wrap the code inside $(window).scroll() but it also doesn't seem to work.

```js
const counters = document.querySelectorAll(".count");
const speed = 200;

counters.forEach((counter) => {
  const updateCount = () => {
    const target = parseInt(+counter.getAttribute("data-target"));
    const count = parseInt(+counter.innerText);
    const increment = Math.trunc(target / speed);
    console.log(increment);

    if (count < target) {
      counter.innerText = count + increment;
      setTimeout(updateCount, 1);
    } else {
      count.innerText = target;
    }


  };
  updateCount();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "verdana", sans-serif;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5rem 0;
  color: #505050;
}

.counter-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.counter {
  text-align: center;
}

.counter h3 {
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.counter h6 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.icon {
  height: 5rem;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="heading">
    Resultater
  </div>
  <div class="counter-container">
    <div class="counter">
      <img src="#" alt="timer" srcset="" class="icon">
      <h3 data-target="200" class="count">0</h3>
      <h6>Text 1</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="counter">
      <img src="#" srcset="" class="icon">
      <h3 data-target="217" class="count">0</h3>
      <h6>Text 2</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="counter">
      <img src="#" alt="night" srcset="" class="icon">
      <h3 data-target="511" class="count">0</h3>
      <h6>Text 3</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand how the code you've included relates to scroll events, it just runs on a loop, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It counts from zero to 3 numbers when loading the page. I want it to not start counting up before the user scrolls. That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is to start your timers after the first scroll event, you can add a single `scroll` event listener, and make use of the `once` config option (So that you only start the animation the first time the user scrolls)

The important part (Where `startCounters` is a function which creates your counters):

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', startCounters, {
  once: true
});
```

Full example:

```js
const counters = document.querySelectorAll(".count");
const speed = 200;

// The code to start the animation is now wrapped in a function
const startCounters = () => {
  counters.forEach((counter) => {
    const updateCount = () => {
      const target = parseInt(+counter.getAttribute("data-target"));
      const count = parseInt(+counter.innerText);
      const increment = Math.trunc(target / speed);
      if (count < target) {
        counter.innerText = count + increment;
        setTimeout(updateCount, 1);
      } else {
        count.innerText = target;
      }
    };
    updateCount();
  });
}

// On the first scroll in this window, call the function to start the counters
window.addEventListener('scroll', startCounters, {
  once: true
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "verdana", sans-serif;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5rem 0;
  color: #505050;
}

.counter-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.counter {
  text-align: center;
}

.counter h3 {
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.counter h6 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.icon {
  height: 5rem;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="heading">
    Resultater
  </div>
  <div class="counter-container">
    <div class="counter">
      <img src="#" alt="timer" srcset="" class="icon">
      <h3 data-target="200" class="count">0</h3>
      <h6>Text 1</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="counter">
      <img src="#" srcset="" class="icon">
      <h3 data-target="217" class="count">0</h3>
      <h6>Text 2</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="counter">
      <img src="#" alt="night" srcset="" class="icon">
      <h3 data-target="511" class="count">0</h3>
      <h6>Text 3</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```